# Configure Java properties in app.config

Tags: java, c#

I am translating some code from `Java` to `C#` and I need to translate the Properties class from `Java` to `C#`. For that, I need to configure the `app.config` file in `C#` but I am not able to understand what the key and value to be added should be.
For example: One of the methods involving properties class in java that I have to translate is:

```
static public Properties putPrefixToProperties (String prefix, Properties pro)
{
    Enumeration en;
    Properties res = new Properties();

    en = pro.propertyNames();

    for (; en.hasMoreElements();)
    {
        String nom = (String) en.nextElement();

        res.setProperty (prefix+nom, pro.getProperty (nom));
    }

    return res;
}
```

Any updates on how to translate such code would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Please post at least some example of what you are tying to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908444/is-there-a-c-sharp-analogue-of-java-util-properties-class).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I guess you want to use AppSettings, example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file

Answer (score 0):

As csharpfolk has written: You may use AppSettings. In your code you may access the settings using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.propertyName
```

This works for application settings (readonly) and user settings (read / write).